# Using Perl to get Checked and put VALUE in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, checkbox, cgi

I'm new to Perl and trying to check to see if a series of checkboxs on an HTML page are checked or not. Each checkbox has a different numeric value I want to add to an array in Perl. I keep getting an undef value. I've combed the web for a reason this is not working and finally broken down to ask for help. For now I just want to display the values retrieved in my log. I'm expecting to see (1, 2) in my results when the checkbox is checked. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below or offer a suggestion as to why I'm getting an "undefined" array? Is there a way to test for connection to the checkbox in question from Perl?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Shipping" id="checkFXG" value="1" enabled />
<input type="checkbox" name="Shipping" id="checkFX2" value="2" enabled />
```

PERL:

```
use CGI;
...

sub updateShipping;
    my $p;
    my $self = shift;
    my $cgi;

    my $sIDquery = CGI->new;
    my $param = $sIDquery->Vars;
    my @sID = $param->{'Shipping'};          # Grab VALUE from checkbox
    my $sID;

    foreach $sID(@sID) {                     # Loop through array displaying each Shipping ID
        warn "**** sID : [$sID]";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `enabled` attribute for inputs.

Comment: There is if you want to display a future option but keep someone from clicking on it. :-) The requirements are to track around 30+ enabled options with potentially others. This is an internal use page and the idea was to keep the "Hey you forgot xyz" from being reported and changing focus.

Comment: That's `disabled` not `enabled`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: What I mean is if I need to release this page but I want to turn off these buttons quickly, I can do a simple "find/replace" and turn all the enabled objects to disabled. Of course as I'm doing this I'm evaluating which items actually stay enabled. A "Replace All" is a bad thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get multiple parameters with the same name, don't use the Vars method, do:

```
my @values = $sIDquery->param('Shipping');
```

There are very few cases where you'd ever want to use Vars.  It is especially unlikely to do what you want for parameters that may not be present (such as checkboxes) or may have more than one value.

Comment: So the sub boils down to `for my $sID ($sIDquery->param('Shipping')) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami: no, `for my $sID (CGI->new->param('Shipping')) { ... }`

Comment: I made the suggested change and dumped the CGI. The CGI is still empty. This perl page runs through an api.cgi and I know that the API uses SOAP. Could something in SOAP be causing the problem between Perl and HTML?

Comment: yes, if you have something else in between it could be consuming the cgi data already.

Comment: Sometimes I really hate working on legacy stuff: Turns out the array, actually whole hash, gets created on page load to populate the webpage then gets dumped and repopulated on SAVE (there is a tiny (new) I missed during code review). That's pretty much why I wasn't seeing my expected results. Thanks for the advice. This worked out.

Comment: do follow my advice anyway, or you will not get what you expect if both boxes are checked